# The type 'PrerenderTagHelper' exists in both 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a ASP Core 1x app that was working fine that I've upgraded to 2.x. It was working fine in dev but once deployed I get the following error about PrerenderTagHelper existing in voth 2.11 and 2.1.13.

```
The type 'PrerenderTagHelper' exists in both 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' and 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices, Version=2.1.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
+
        private global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Prerendering.PrerenderTagHelper __Microsoft_AspNetCore_SpaServices_Prerendering_PrerenderTagHelper;
```

I've added MvcRazorCompileOnPublish and PreserveCompilationContext to the csproj file which at least shows the same error in dev as when deployed. Below is my csproj.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VersionPrefix>1.5.0</VersionPrefix>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <AssemblyName>src</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PackageId>src</PackageId>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="node_modules\**\*" />
    <None Update="ClientApp\dist\**\*;Data\**\*;PhantomJS\**\*;wkhtmltopdf\**\*;Views\**\*;Images\**\*;Resources\**\*;nlog.config;wwwroot\**\*">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None> 
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"  />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="1.60.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper.FastCrud" Version="2.5.0.39" />
    <PackageReference Include="MailKit" Version="1.10.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="EPPlus.Core" Version="1.5.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.Core" Version="1.6.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.SqlServer" Version="1.6.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.AspNetCore" Version="1.6.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Magick.NET-Q8-AnyCPU" Version="7.0.6.601" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="PrepublishScript" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
    <Exec Command="npm install" />
    <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.generate-handover.js --env.prod" />
    <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.handover.js --env.prod" />
    <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod" />
    <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod" />
  </Target>


</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Skipped to ASP Core 3.0 and it's working again. Did not workout what caused it to fail in 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

In .net core 2.x projects you can use 2.1.13 nuget version instead of 2.1.1

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices" Version="2.1.13" />
```